# Error running code on Uno r4 wifi which works great on Nano

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have some code that I can use to turn my TV off and on with an arduino nano and an IR LED. It works great. However, I want to run it on an uno r4 wifi so it can be controlled remotely. When I upload the same code to the uno r4, I get this error: (I put it in a block so its not so bad to read.

```
/*
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irISR.cpp:18:5: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 ISR (TIMER_INTR_NAME)
     ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp: In member function 'void IRrecv::enableIRIn()':
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:105:2: error: 'cli' was not declared in this scope
  cli();
  ^~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:105:2: note: suggested alternative: 'cbi'
  cli();
  ^~~
  cbi
In file included from /Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremote.h:24:0,
                 from /Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:1:
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:236:3: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
   TCCR2A = _BV(WGM21); \
   ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:236:16: error: 'WGM21' was not declared in this scope
   TCCR2A = _BV(WGM21); \
                ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:236:12: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope
   TCCR2A = _BV(WGM21); \
            ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:236:12: note: suggested alternative: '_B'
   TCCR2A = _BV(WGM21); \
            ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:237:3: error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope
   TCCR2B = _BV(CS21); \
   ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:237:16: error: 'CS21' was not declared in this scope
   TCCR2B = _BV(CS21); \
                ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremote.h:24:0,
                 from /Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:1:
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp: In member function 'void IRsend::mark(int)':
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:210:30: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_PWM    (TCCR2A |= _BV(COM2B1))
                              ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:24:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_ENABLE_PWM; // Enable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:237:16: note: suggested alternative: 'CS'
   TCCR2B = _BV(CS21); \
                ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:238:3: error: 'OCR2A' was not declared in this scope
   OCR2A  = TIMER_COUNT_TOP / 8; \
   ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:239:3: error: 'TCNT2' was not declared in this scope
   TCNT2  = 0; \
   ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:210:44: error: 'COM2B1' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_PWM    (TCCR2A |= _BV(COM2B1))
                                            ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:24:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_ENABLE_PWM; // Enable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:239:3: note: suggested alternative: 'SCNx32'
   TCNT2  = 0; \
   ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:110:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL'
  TIMER_CONFIG_NORMAL();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:212:30: error: 'TIMSK2' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_INTR   (TIMSK2 = _BV(OCIE2A))
                              ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:113:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_INTR'
  TIMER_ENABLE_INTR;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:212:43: error: 'OCIE2A' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_INTR   (TIMSK2 = _BV(OCIE2A))
                                           ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:113:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_INTR'
  TIMER_ENABLE_INTR;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:212:39: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_INTR   (TIMSK2 = _BV(OCIE2A))
                                       ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:113:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_INTR'
  TIMER_ENABLE_INTR;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:210:40: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_PWM    (TCCR2A |= _BV(COM2B1))
                                        ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:24:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_ENABLE_PWM; // Enable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:210:40: note: suggested alternative: '_B'
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_PWM    (TCCR2A |= _BV(COM2B1))
                                        ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:24:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_ENABLE_PWM; // Enable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp: In member function 'void IRsend::space(int)':
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:211:30: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_DISABLE_PWM   (TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1)))
                              ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:35:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_DISABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_DISABLE_PWM; // Disable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:212:39: note: suggested alternative: '_B'
 #define TIMER_ENABLE_INTR   (TIMSK2 = _BV(OCIE2A))
                                       ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:113:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_ENABLE_INTR'
  TIMER_ENABLE_INTR;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:117:2: error: 'sei' was not declared in this scope
  sei();  // enable interrupts
  ^~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:211:46: error: 'COM2B1' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_DISABLE_PWM   (TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1)))
                                              ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:35:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_DISABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_DISABLE_PWM; // Disable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irRecv.cpp:117:2: note: suggested alternative: 'sbi'
  sei();  // enable interrupts
  ^~~
  sbi
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:211:42: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_DISABLE_PWM   (TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1)))
                                          ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:35:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_DISABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_DISABLE_PWM; // Disable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:211:42: note: suggested alternative: '_B'
 #define TIMER_DISABLE_PWM   (TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1)))
                                          ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:35:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_DISABLE_PWM'
  TIMER_DISABLE_PWM; // Disable pin 3 PWM output
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp: In member function 'void IRsend::enableIROut(int)':
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:213:30: error: 'TIMSK2' was not declared in this scope
 #define TIMER_DISABLE_INTR  (TIMSK2 = 0)
                              ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:54:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_DISABLE_INTR'
  TIMER_DISABLE_INTR; //Timer2 Overflow Interrupt
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:218:2: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
  TCCR2A               = _BV(WGM20); \
  ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:218:29: error: 'WGM20' was not declared in this scope
  TCCR2A               = _BV(WGM20); \
                             ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:218:25: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope
  TCCR2A               = _BV(WGM20); \
                         ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:218:25: note: suggested alternative: '_B'
  TCCR2A               = _BV(WGM20); \
                         ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:219:2: error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope
  TCCR2B               = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20); \
  ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:219:29: error: 'WGM22' was not declared in this scope
  TCCR2B               = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20); \
                             ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:219:42: error: 'CS20' was not declared in this scope
  TCCR2B               = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20); \
                                          ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:219:42: note: suggested alternative: 'CS'
  TCCR2B               = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20); \
                                          ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:220:2: error: 'OCR2A' was not declared in this scope
  OCR2A                = pwmval; \
  ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/IRremoteInt.h:221:2: error: 'OCR2B' was not declared in this scope
  OCR2B                = pwmval / 3; \
  ^
/Users/-/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IRremote/irSend.cpp:64:2: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ'
  TIMER_CONFIG_KHZ(khz);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
*/
```

This is the code which I am uploading:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int LED = 13;
IRsend irsend;

void setup() {
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(7,INPUT_PULLUP); 
}

void loop() {  
    if (digitalRead(7) == HIGH){
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12); // 12 bit wide Sony TV power code
            delay(40);
        }
     } 
     else digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
     
     delay(100);  
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas why the code is working fine on the nano but gives this error when uploaded to the uno r4? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need IRremote library compatible with completely different microcontroller (aka compatible with Uno R4 / Renesas ARM)

Comment: This is cross posted at forum.arduino.cc and is getting attention there..  voting to close for cross post.

Comment: OP, please let one site have a chance before you pepper your question all over the internet.  It wastes peoples time if they're giving you advice you already got on another site.  It is not increasing your audience.  Quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IRremote library should be fully compatible with Uno R4 and you might have either old version or some different version than listed in https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/irremote/

I tried your code by selecting Uno R4 Minima and only I had to install the IRremote library (in "Sketch" -> "Add Library" -> "Manage libraries" (or CTRL+SHIFT+I) then typed "irremote" into the search and install).

```
Using library IRremote at version 4.3.0 in folder: C:\Users\m\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote 
"C:\\Users\\m\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\arm-none-eabi-gcc\\7-2017q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-size" -A "C:\\Users\\m\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\D52ECE48380979A802CA96953101D2E8/sketch_mar14a.ino.elf"
Sketch uses 54668 bytes (20%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Global variables use 4960 bytes (15%) of dynamic memory, leaving 27808 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 32768 bytes.
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to update my version of the library for the sketch to upload. Appreciate the comment.